# Add list elements to end of list of lists

Tags: python

I have a list of values that I want to add its elements to the end of each list in a list of lists. Is there a Pythonic or efficient way to solve this?

For example, given:

```
x = [['a','b','c'],['d','e','f'],['g','h','i']]
y = [1,2,3]
```

I would expect:
`[['a', 'b', 'c', 1], ['d', 'e', 'f', 2], ['g', 'h', 'i', 3]]`

I've tried:

```
list(zip(x,y))
```

But, this produces:

```
[(['a', 'b', 'c'], 1), (['d', 'e', 'f'], 2), (['g', 'h', 'i'], 3)]
```

I can solve it with an inefficient loop like this:

```
new_data = []
for i,x in enumerate(x):
    x.append(y[i])
    new_data.append(x)

print(new_data)
[['a', 'b', 'c', 1], ['d', 'e', 'f', 2], ['g', 'h', 'i', 3]]
```

Comment: Do you want to append to the existing lists or do you want to create new ones?

Comment: This is to explicitly use this in `pandas` later on.

Comment: Efficiency isn't purely measured in lines of code. What's 'inefficient' about your working solution?

Comment: @jarmod - i'm certainly not saying my code is inefficient because it's a more than a one-liner. looping over lists tends to be slower if there's a vectroized solution out there.

Comment: There is very little "vectorisation" to be had outside the realm of efficient libraries like `pandas` and `numpy` - you are looking for a pure Python solution, correct?

Comment: Could you answer the existing-vs-new question?

Comment: @Grismar - solution does not need to be pure python

Comment: @KellyBundy - either is fine.

Answer (score 7):

To build a new list, I might do:

```
>>> x = [['a','b','c'],['d','e','f'],['g','h','i']]
>>> y = [1,2,3]
>>> [a + [b] for a, b in zip(x, y)]
[['a', 'b', 'c', 1], ['d', 'e', 'f', 2], ['g', 'h', 'i', 3]]
```

If you want to modify `x` in place, you don't need to use `enumerate`, just loop over the `zip` and `append` the y-elements to the x-elements:

```
>>> for a, b in zip(x, y):
...     a.append(b)
...
>>> x
[['a', 'b', 'c', 1], ['d', 'e', 'f', 2], ['g', 'h', 'i', 3]]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can unpack the first list when constructing the sublists using `zip()`:

```py
[[*item1, item2] for item1, item2 in zip(x, y)]
```

---

For example:

```py
x = [['a','b','c'],['d','e','f'],['g','h','i']]
y = [1,2,3]

print([[*item1, item2] for item1, item2 in zip(x, y)])
```

outputs:

```py
[['a', 'b', 'c', 1], ['d', 'e', 'f', 2], ['g', 'h', 'i', 3]]
```

Answer (score 1):

Potentially more efficient solution using `collections.deque` and `map` to quickly run `append` over the list+value pairs:

```
deque(map(list.append, x, y), 0)
```

Benchmark (using 1000 times longer outer lists):

```
189 us  191 us  192 us  with_loop
 77 us   77 us   77 us  with_deque
```

The `0` btw tells `deque` to just consume, not store anything, so it has very little constant memory overhead. And it's [very fast](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50938015/12671057). That's why it's used in itertools' [consume recipe](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes) and in more-itertools' [consume function](https://more-itertools.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#more_itertools.consume).

Benchmark code ([Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jVHbisMgEH3PV8zLohYpSQPLEuiXhBBMYlohXlYN2@7PZ9W0afq2woBzZs5xjmPu/qpV@WXssgx8hB/hr@2ktcE3CndSZRDOqC0wCh0IBb/irRQPOzJjuBpwR7JsExn498z3rSsgmcGTcP7BoZA6KOSBO1otwQvJhQchjbYeLDec@bXS62nivRdauWc5aQbirHoH59f0dDdD5l2s1XWTjLTRRSI02ZZbpi4cn/Kd4dhCwbun6USJgNtZvyVhxBBFXYgeNbRGQ7jxEGPKLuF2DSFQ02y8e@QV9ETLF@Z6NvGAF3mevz/A6mo3@zpr6ibraiJ624sfzqvaBvkgI4XC63fiicluYFXyiB8LULPsuD0XhLxY7rlZT7J//YmxQnl8wOijHGB2gOADsIcDFPxzHdZHrgu740HVkboqm/B4FDq2rWKSty1Zlj8)):

```
def with_loop(x, y):
    for a, b in zip(x, y):
        a.append(b)

def with_deque(x, y):
    deque(map(list.append, x, y), 0)

from timeit import repeat
from collections import deque

funcs = with_loop, with_deque
tss = [[] for _ in funcs]
for _ in range(20):
    for func, ts in zip(funcs, tss):
        x = [['a','b','c'],['d','e','f'],['g','h','i']]
        y = [1,2,3]
        scale = 1000
        x = [a[:] for _ in range(scale) for a in x]
        y *= scale
        t = min(repeat(lambda: func(x, y), number=1))
        ts.append(t)
for func, ts in zip(funcs, tss):
    print(*('%3d us ' % (t * 1e6) for t in sorted(ts)[:3]), func.__name__)
```

Comment: Note this use of `deque` also appears in the `consume` recipe in the `itertools` documentation.

Comment: @chepner Yes, mentioned that and other things now. Normally I don't, as normally it's just part of my benchmarking code. But since I'm using it in a solution here, it makes sense to talk about it.

Answer (score 1):

The solutions provided by most here are all very similar in performance, and similar to your own.

The solution by @kellybundy is the only one that stands out and I doubt you'll find a faster one, given how minimal it is and the fact that it already relies on Python's fast internals. (please accept their answer, not this one, if you agree)

Consider:

```
from copy import deepcopy
from timeit import timeit
from random import choice
from collections import deque

chars = 'abcdefghijkl'

texts = [[choice(chars) for _ in range(3)] for _ in range(1000)]
nums = [n for n in range(1000)]


def combine0(xss, ys):
    return xss  # only here to show the cost of any overhead


def combine1(xss, ys):
    result = []
    for i, xs in enumerate(xss):
        xs.append(ys[i])
        result.append(xs)
    return result


def combine2(xss, ys):
    return [xs + [y] for xs, y in zip(xss, ys)]


def combine3(xss, ys):
    return [[*xs, y] for xs, y in zip(xss, ys)]


def combine4(xss, ys):
    result = []
    for xs, y in zip(xss, ys):
        xs.append(y)
        result.append(xs)
    return result


def combine5(xss, ys):
    deque(map(list.append, xss, ys), 0)
    return xss


assert combine1(deepcopy(texts), nums) == combine2(deepcopy(texts), nums) == combine3(deepcopy(texts), nums) == combine4(deepcopy(texts), nums) == combine5(deepcopy(texts), nums)

for _ in range(10):
    for n, f in enumerate((combine0, combine1, combine2, combine3, combine4, combine5)):
        copies = iter([deepcopy(texts) for _ in range(1000)])
        time = timeit(lambda: f(next(copies), nums), number=1000) / 1000
        print(f.__name__, f'{time * 1e6 :6.2f} µs')
    print()
```

Result:

```
combine0   0.20 µs
combine1  82.28 µs
combine2  93.37 µs
combine3  73.44 µs
combine4  65.77 µs
combine5  16.27 µs

combine0   0.24 µs
combine1  75.62 µs
combine2  92.81 µs
combine3  91.56 µs
combine4  66.39 µs
combine5  17.73 µs

combine0   0.22 µs
combine1  84.68 µs
combine2  96.62 µs
combine3  87.32 µs
combine4  73.86 µs
combine5  15.44 µs

etc.
```

This shows that there's quite a bit of variation in runtime dependent on all sort of other factors, but there's a clear advantage for `combine5`, which uses @kellybundy's solution.

The lines with `0` show the performance of the function that does nothing, to show that we're actually measuring the performance of the functions and not just the overhead of the calls etc.

Note: the `deepcopy`s are there to avoid modifying the same list repeatedly and they are created before the test to avoid the creation of copies affecting the measurement.

Comment: `deepcopy(texts)` is really slow, the whole benchmark runs 4x faster for me if I use `[text[:] for text in texts]` instead.

Comment: That would get you a list with the original lists, which are being modified by some of the solutions, so each iteration would add to a growing list? `deepcopy` ensures the inner lists are copied as well?

Comment: Since the test runs a 1000 iterations, you're already getting millisecond values printed, unless I'm making a logic error here I'm missing? I did update the call to `deque` and the print statement, agree there.

Comment: The `[:]` makes copies.

Comment: Ah sorry I see, yes I agree - however, I'm going to leave it, as that's just optimising the performance of the test, not affecting the functions themselves.

Comment: I meant milliseconds for the timeit result (so yes, microseconds for each iteration). Though the unit wasn't really the point, I just find it easier to compare the times if I don't have to ignore zeros and search for the first non-zero digit.

Comment: Well... for me, with `deepcopy`, it literally takes too long to work. Because I'm running other people's code on tio.run (so I feel safe without having to check for malicious stuff). And it has a time limit of 60 seconds, which this exceeds. I can reduce the repetitions/lengths, but that's work and the value suffers. And in general it's just annoying having to wait :-)