# Suggestions for optimization Python

Tags: python, optimization

This is a fairly straight forward programming problem in Python and I am looking for suggestions for further optimization. I am successfully processing in time except for very large strings. I am not looking for code rather areas that I should research for optimization improvements. I have already identified that I can skip even numbers reducing the loop operation and given the nature of the operations the pattern eventually repeats which is why I track when repeat occurs. This allows me break out if n > repeat. I am not positive if converting the string to a list is the most effective.

Problem:

> We have a string s and we have a number n that indicates the number of times to run the function. Here is a function that takes your string, concatenates the even-indexed chars to the front, odd-indexed chars to the back. You perform this operation n times.

Example:

> example where s = "qwertyuio" and n = 2:
> after 1 iteration  s = "qetuowryi"
> after 2 iterations s = "qtorieuwy"
> return "qtorieuwy"

```
def jumbled_string(s, n):

sl = list(s)
repeat = 0
for y in range(0,n):
    for i in range(1, (len(sl)//2)+1):
        sl.append(sl.pop(i))
    if repeat == 0 and ''.join(sl) == s:
        repeat = y+1
        break
if repeat != 0:
    afterrepeat = n%repeat
    for y in range(0,afterrepeat):
        for i in range(1, (len(sl)//2)+1):
            sl.append(sl.pop(i))

return ''.join(sl)
```

Comment: What's the role of the number `n`?

Comment: One or more examples of input and expected output would also be helpful.

Comment: @trincot:   i was going to ask exactly the same.  what does `n` do in the question ?

Comment: It seems `n` just repeats the operation. So `s = 'abcdefghijklmn'; for _ in range(3): s = s[::2] + s[1::2]` gives the same result as the OP's function (i.e. `jumbled_string(s, 3)` => `'aidlgbjemhckfn'`).

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because questions about improving working code are a better fit for [codereview.se], but remember to check their [on-topic](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) page first

Comment: my apologies for not including the necessary information. @ekhumoro is correct that you repeat the operation n times.

Comment: @PranavHosangadi if this is in the wrong section, my apologies.

Comment: @user19620526 Are there any other conditions related to how you're meant to solve the problem? I assume use of python's extended slice syntax is not in the spirit of the question. If you want to keep your question on topic, you should edit it to include some specific type of optimisation you are trying (and presumably failing) to implement.

Comment: @ekhumoro slicing is acceptable. I was unaware / lack the knowledge that I could use slicing to extract the even / odd characters within the string.  In review, it is apparent that looping through each character, albeit each odd character, is not as efficient as performing the slice operation. I will work on improving the completeness of my submissions

Comment: `sl.pop(i)` is inefficient. Making your shuffling code polynomial time instead of linear time

Comment: The interesting part of this is calculating how many iterations are required before the original string is repeated (based on the length of the string). For strings of length `2^n`, this is simply `n` iterations; but for intervening values, the pattern is quite hard to discern. If a formula could be worked out, this would obviously lead to a huge optimisation, since it could drastically reduce the total number of string concatenations for large values of `n`.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you mean by "pattern repeats". But if we stick to the problem statement, it's a one liner in Python:

```
s='abecidofug'
from itertools import chain
s2 = ''.join(chain([s[c] for c in range(0, len(s), 2)],[s[c] for c in range(1, len(s), 2)]))
s2
'aeioubcdfg'
```

Comment: this does it the wrong way around, should be even indices at the front

Comment: i failed to include that the n signifies how many times you execute the even- odd operation. Depending on the string length, over X iterations the string will return to its original form. so even if n is 1000000, if the string is only 10 characters, find when it repeats and just find the mod n/repeat value to reduce the number of times i have to loop.

Comment: oops, editing the answer - just invert the 0 and the 1

Answer (score 0):

You don't explain what n does. The statement is this:

```
def jumbled_string(s: str) -> str:
    even = s[::2]
    odd = s[1::2]
    return even+odd

print(jumbled_string("0123456789"))
>>>0246813579
```

Comment: my mistake, you repeat the function n times.

Comment: Thanks Colim, this approached removed the need for my loop through each character, pop, and append. This resulted in the performance increase necessary. I don't have the reputation to vote, but i appreciate your time.

Comment: the ```.join```s are pointless, and results in a significant speed decrease, a factor of 3 on my machine for ```s = 'abcdefghijklmn'```

Comment: @Nin17 thank you for the suggestion. It was are remnant of when I was originally converting the string to a list.

Comment: @Nin17 fixed. I must enter minimum length of characters

Answer (score 0):

In python 3.8+ (due to `:=` operator) you could do it like this:

```
import collections

def jumbled_string(s: str, n: int) -> str:
    generator = (s:=s[::2]+s[1::2] for _ in range(n))
    collections.deque(generator, maxlen=0)
    return s
```

Using [collections.deque](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.deque) as this is the [Fastest (most Pythonic) way to consume an iterator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50937966/fastest-most-pythonic-way-to-consume-an-iterator).
Though, for small `n` I'm finding it faster to use:

```
def jumbled_string(s: str, n: int) -> str:
    for _ in (s:=s[::2]+s[1::2] for _ in range(n)):
        pass
    return s
```

Test:

```
jumbled_string("qwertyuio", 2)
```

Output:

```
'qtorieuwy'
```

Comment: thank you for the link, interesting read about collections.deque and something i need to explore more. I appreciate it.

Comment: this is a terrible use of a generator expression (for side effects) and the walrus operator. A *regular loop* would be faster and more clear. This really adds no advantage

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga if the string is large, they are the same speed

Comment: I doubt it, a regular for-loop should be faster than the generator expression because there is no additional overhead of the generator (although very recent python versions have made the overhead of a generator much smaller). But the biggest problem is the style here - generator expressions are for expressing *mapping/filtering operations*, not for side-effects. This is a very convoluted way to do `for _ in range(n): s = s[:] + s[1::2]`, which will be faster than `for _ in (s:=s[::2]+s[1::2] for _ in range(n))` because you have an extra, totally pointless layer of iteration.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga you can doubt it all you like, I've timed it and they're the same in both 3.9.13 and 3.10.5. Yh well tbh just discovered ```:=``` so sticking it in wherever

Comment: @Nin17 you haven't even posted your profiling code, so everyone should doubt it. Using the `timeit` module, I'm getting about a 20% speed penalty for the needless generator version. e.g., `def bar(s, n): for _ in range(n): s = s = s[::2] + s[1::2]` and `def foo(s, n): for _ in (s:=s[::2]+s[1::2] for _ in range(n)): pass` then `import timeit` and `timeit.timeit("foo(s, 10)", setup='from __main__ import foo; s = "a"*100')` vs `timeit.timeit("bar(s, 10)", setup='from __main__ import foo, bar; s = "a"*100')`

Comment: yh well when I say large I don't mean ```'a'*100```